# Sending response of Servlet back to the JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm doing a project where there is an insertion operation. First I'm sending the required data from my form in `JSP` to my `Servlet`.

I want to get a response from the `Servlet` back to the `JSP` page so that I can display a message that the value has been inserted successfully.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: there is no magic behind your problem. just google it and you will find a lot of good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method in seperate class or same servlet that inserts in to DATABASE and returns boolean.

based on the return of your method you can redirect servlet response to any of the jsp or html with a extra parameter appended in URL

eg

```
if(insertToDB(Bean n)) {

   response.redirect("success.jsp?msg=hi");
} else {
    response.redirect("faliure.jsp?msg=bye");
}

public boolean insertTODB(Bean n){

//DB insertion logic return true false on success failure accordingly



}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `RequestDispatcher` class in your servlet ,

```
request.setAttribute("message","Succesfully inserted!");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("yourJspPage.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
```

And in your jsp print it using EL,

```
<p>${mesage}</p>
```